# rails Internal Server Error expected Array (got String) for param `id'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2

When I try to submit form data I get this following error

```
 Internal Server Error expected Array (got String) for param `id'
```

Earlier it was working fine, I have made few changes in the text fields class and Javascript. Please explain the above error and solution to it.

Solved : All the ID's were not unique that is why I was getting this error

Comment: without any code it is impossible to tell whats going on, it could be anything

Comment: well its a huge code, it was working fine earlier and all of the fields in form are having unique ID. Does it make any sense?

Comment: no, it does not. We need to see the code that is generating the error.

Comment: @user2634485 Post the Snippets. There will be a linenumber where the exception is thrown. What version of rails is it? 3.1, 3, 3.2? It whould be better to follow this guide and edit your question: http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx

Answer (score 1):

> Please explain the above error and solution to it.

The above error is because you're passing a string somewhere in your code where you actually expect an array.

The solution is to find the place that you're passing the string rather than the array, to then trace through your code to find out how it is that you're managing to pass a string rather than an array, and then to fix the code so that you properly pass an array rather than a string.

Without additional code and context, the question is impossible to answer further. If you've been following proper source control procedures, you might consider using `git bisect` or your SCM's equivalent to locate the commit in which the bug was introduced.

Comment: I didn't know about git bisect.  Looks very useful - thanks!

Comment: `git bisect` is awesome, and after it saves your ass a few times, you'll find it encourages more and more granular commits, too. All around win!